# For $f_\lambda(x) = \lambda x (1-x) $, $1 < \lambda < 3$, show orbit of each $x \in (0,1)$ converges to $1 - \frac{1}{\lambda}$

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $f_\lambda :[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be the logistic map with parameter $1 < \lambda < 3$,
$$f_\lambda(x) = \lambda x (1-x).$$
The two fixed points of $f_\lambda$ are $0$ and $a = 1 - \frac{1}{\lambda}$.

> Prove that for every $x \in (0,1)$, the orbit $\{f^{\circ k}_\lambda(x) \}_{k=1}^\infty$ converges to $a = 1 - \frac{1}{\lambda}$.

This fact is claimed in Chapter 13 of Falconer's Fractal Geometry textbook (page 174). I am trying to show it analytically.

After choosing an initial $x_0 \in (0,1)$, we generate the iterates:

$$x_1 = \lambda x_0 (1 - x_0), x_2 = \lambda x_1 (1 - x_1), \dots .$$

If we write 
$$x_k = a + \delta_k ,\quad \frac{1}{\lambda} - 1 \le \delta_k \le \frac{1}{\lambda}, $$

then using Taylor's formula we get

$$\delta_{k+1} = (2 - (1+\delta_k)\lambda)\delta_k$$

But now it's not clear to me how to use this to obtain convergence. We would like to have $|(2 - (1+\delta_k)\lambda)|$ very small to use a contraction argument. But, for instance, if $x_0 = 0.9$ and $\lambda = 2.7$, then $(2 - (1+\delta_0)\lambda) = -1.43$. Also the fact that the $\delta_k$'s  are signed seems to cause issues. So it seems some particular cases need to be analyzed individually before one proves the entire result.

Any hints or solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would first show that $f_{\lambda}$ is contractive on an interval that is symmetric about $1/2$. In fact, any compact sub-interval of $$\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\lambda},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\lambda}\right)$$ should do. Then, since $f_{\lambda}$ is increasing on $[0,1/2]$ and symmetric, we know that any point will eventually land in that interval where the function is contractive.